# How to convert a sda image (SuSE 10.3) to a valid vdmk-file (VMware VM )?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

How to convert a sda image (SuSE 10.3) to a valid vdmk-file (VMware VM )?

I have created with "dd" comand an image from the "sda" on a running SuSE 10.3 computer. Now I want to virtualize it to run it on a VM in ESXi (VMware).

Is this the right approach? Is there a smarter way?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to make the image of a system when it's not running, but other than that, you can use `qemu-img` to convert the raw disk image to a vmdk file:

```
qemu-img dd -f raw -O vmdk if=RAW_IMAGE of=VMDK_IMAGE.vmdk
```

Comment: Thank you for the anwser!

I've to install qemu on SuSE 10.3 first, but:


________________________________________________________________
´Downloading package qemu-0.9.0.cvs-35.x86_64, 9.5 M (34.1 M unpacked)
* Installing: qemu-0.9.0.cvs-35 [0%]Installation of [S1:1][package]qemu-0.9.0.cvs-35.x86_64 failed:
(with --nodeps --force) Error: Subprocess failed. Error: RPM failed:

(A)bort, (R)etry, (I)gnore? r`
_______________________________________________________________

Is SuSE 10.3 too old for this?

Comment: Perhaps you can access the image from a newer distro. Can you copy the image file elsewhere and run a newer distro there? Or boot a Live CD/USB with another distro on the same hardware. qemu may not be a package included on most Live distros, but you can certainly build a NixOS live CD/USB with qemu included.